# Unable to show the tooltip values for stacked area chart in a single tooltip

Tags: javascript, d3.js, stacked-area-chart

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
    }
    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
    .x.axis path {
      display: none;
    }
    .line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var myData = "date New York San Francisco Austin\n\
20111001 63.4 62.7 72.2\n\
20111002 58.0 59.9 67.7\n\
20111003 53.3 59.1 69.4\n\
20111004 55.7 58.8 68.0\n\
20111005 64.2 58.7 72.4\n\
20111006 58.8 57.0 77.0\n\
20111007 57.9 56.7 82.3\n\
20111008 61.8 56.8 78.9\n\
20111009 69.3 56.7 68.8\n\
20111010 71.2 60.1 68.7\n\
20111011 68.7 61.1 70.3\n\
20111012 61.8 61.5 75.3\n\
20111013 63.0 64.3 76.6\n\
20111014 66.9 67.1 66.6\n\
20111015 61.7 64.6 68.0\n\
20111016 61.8 61.6 70.6\n\
20111017 62.8 61.1 71.1\n\
20111018 60.8 59.2 70.0\n\
20111019 62.1 58.9 61.6\n\
20111020 65.1 57.2 57.4\n\
20111021 55.6 56.4 64.3\n\
20111022 54.4 60.7 72.4\n";

    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 80,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 50
      },
      width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;

    var x = d3.time.scale()
      .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([height, 0]);

    var color = d3.scale.category20();

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left");

    var line = d3.svg.line()
      .interpolate("basis")
      .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.date);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.temperature);
      });

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var data = d3.tsv.parse(myData);

    color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
      return key !== "date";
    }));

    data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    });

    var cities = color.domain().map(function(name) {
      return {
        name: name,
        values: data.map(function(d) {
          return {
            date: d.date,
            temperature: +d[name]
          };
        })
      };
    });

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
      return d.date;
    }));

    y.domain([
      d3.min(cities, function(c) {
        return d3.min(c.values, function(v) {
          return v.temperature;
        });
      }),
      d3.max(cities, function(c) {
        return d3.max(c.values, function(v) {
          return v.temperature;
        });
      })
    ]);

    var legend = svg.selectAll('g')
      .data(cities)
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'legend');

    legend.append('rect')
      .attr('x', width - 20)
      .attr('y', function(d, i) {
        return i * 20;
      })
      .attr('width', 10)
      .attr('height', 10)
      .style('fill', function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      });

    legend.append('text')
      .attr('x', width - 8)
      .attr('y', function(d, i) {
        return (i * 20) + 9;
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
      });

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Temperature (ºF)");

    var city = svg.selectAll(".city")
      .data(cities)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "city");

    city.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        return line(d.values);
      })
      .style("stroke", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      });

    city.append("text")
      .datum(function(d) {
        return {
          name: d.name,
          value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]
        };
      })
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.temperature) + ")";
      })
      .attr("x", 3)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
      });

    var mouseG = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "mouse-over-effects");

    mouseG.append("path") // this is the black vertical line to follow mouse
      .attr("class", "mouse-line")
      .style("stroke", "black")
      .style("stroke-width", "1px")
      .style("opacity", "0");

    var lines = document.getElementsByClassName('line');

    var mousePerLine = mouseG.selectAll('.mouse-per-line')
      .data(cities)
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "mouse-per-line");

    mousePerLine.append("rect")
      .attr("width", width / 2)
      .attr("height", 30)
      .style("padding", "5px")
      .style("stroke", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      })
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      })
      .style("stroke-width", "1px")
      .style("opacity", "0")
      .attr('x', 10);


    mousePerLine.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .style("stroke", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      })
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      })
      .style("stroke-width", "1px")
      .style("opacity", "0");

    mousePerLine.append("text")
      .attr("transform", "translate(15,13)");

    mouseG.append('svg:rect') // append a rect to catch mouse movements on canvas
      .attr('width', width) // can't catch mouse events on a g element
      .attr('height', height)
      .attr('fill', 'none')
      .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
      .on('mouseout', function() { // on mouse out hide line, circles and text
        d3.select(".mouse-line")
          .style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line rect")
          .style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
          .style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
          .style("opacity", "0");
      })
      .on('mouseover', function() { // on mouse in show line, circles and text
        d3.select(".mouse-line")
          .style("opacity", "1");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line rect")
          .style("opacity", "0.5");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
          .style("opacity", "1");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
          .style("opacity", "1");
      })
      .on('mousemove', function() { // mouse moving over canvas
        var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
        d3.select(".mouse-line")
          .attr("d", function() {
            var d = "M" + mouse[0] + "," + height;
            d += " " + mouse[0] + "," + 0;
            return d;
          });

        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line")
          .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
            console.log(width / mouse[0])
            var xDate = x.invert(mouse[0]),
              bisect = d3.bisector(function(d) {
                return d.date;
              }).right;
            idx = bisect(d.values, xDate);

            var beginning = 0,
              end = lines[i].getTotalLength(),
              target = null;

            while (true) {
              target = Math.floor((beginning + end) / 2);
              pos = lines[i].getPointAtLength(target);
              if ((target === end || target === beginning) && pos.x !== mouse[0]) {
                break;
              }
              if (pos.x > mouse[0]) end = target;
              else if (pos.x < mouse[0]) beginning = target;
              else break; //position found
            }

            d3.select(this).select('text')
              .text(y.invert(pos.y).toFixed(2));

            return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + pos.y + ")";
          });
      });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Hello. I am new to D3. I am trying to make a stacked area chart using D3 and on mouse hover I want to show all the multiple data values inside a single rectangle for each area chart. Till now I have achieved to show the data values on mouse hover in separate individual rectangles for each data value. Please help me with some suggestions/ tips about how to achieve this. I am really stuck and struggling. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: how exactly do you want ? what about circles and the position in case of single tool tip  ?

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. I want that, when the mouse hovers, the line should show the circles in their respective places to highlight the data points and there should be a single rectangle beside the line to show the data rather than the 3 rectangles as is shown now in my case. On mouse hover, when the circles highlight the data points the respective data values are to be shown in a single rectangle rather than individual rectangles. I saw a link http://nvd3.org/livecode/index.html#codemirrorNav, but it uses NVD3. But my requirement is to use only D3. Is it possible?? Please help me.

Comment: Please help me with some suggestions like it can be done or not using D3?

Comment: If you can tell me how is the text and circle are getting updated I might be able to help

Comment: getting single rectangle is easy, just while binding data give cities as a single element, like [cities] instead of cities

Comment: Hello, Variable "mouseG" having class "mouse-line" is appending the vertical line that gets displayed on mouse hover. "mousePerLine" is having the class attribute "mouse-per-line" which next appends the "circle", "rect" and "text" to show the data on mouse over. On mouse hovered, .on('mouseover', function() { // (on mouse in show line, circles and text and rect)  d3.select(".mouse-line")  d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line rect")  d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle") d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text") gets called for each area chart.

Comment: Now the rectangle and the text are called for every value and created separately for each data value every time. How to create only one rectangle every time and append all the data inside it without creating a new rectangle every time. I want that, "rect" will be called once but "text" again and again to update the data inside "rect" on mouseover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this is as ugly as it gets. I some how managed to solve the issue(I am also new to d3).

I will explain how I solved. There should and will be better ways to achieve your goal.

1. First I added a single group instead of three groups
2. Next added data separately for each svg element i.e, rect, text and circle.
3. on mouse hover, I selected the mouse-per-line class elements then, I transformed each svg element individually.
4. For appending the rectangle, I stored the heights in an array and took the average for setting the position of rectangle. Similarly did the same transformation for text.

**Once again, mine is just a working model, there will/should be more elegant ways to achieve the same.**

If someone can modify or suggest edits, it would be helpful.
Hope this helps.

```js
    var myData = "date New York San Francisco Austin\n\
20111001 63.4 62.7 72.2\n\
20111002 58.0 59.9 67.7\n\
20111003 53.3 59.1 69.4\n\
20111004 55.7 58.8 68.0\n\
20111005 64.2 58.7 72.4\n\
20111006 58.8 57.0 77.0\n\
20111007 57.9 56.7 82.3\n\
20111008 61.8 56.8 78.9\n\
20111009 69.3 56.7 68.8\n\
20111010 71.2 60.1 68.7\n\
20111011 68.7 61.1 70.3\n\
20111012 61.8 61.5 75.3\n\
20111013 63.0 64.3 76.6\n\
20111014 66.9 67.1 66.6\n\
20111015 61.7 64.6 68.0\n\
20111016 61.8 61.6 70.6\n\
20111017 62.8 61.1 71.1\n\
20111018 60.8 59.2 70.0\n\
20111019 62.1 58.9 61.6\n\
20111020 65.1 57.2 57.4\n\
20111021 55.6 56.4 64.3\n\
20111022 54.4 60.7 72.4\n";

    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 80,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 50
      },
      width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;

    var x = d3.time.scale()
      .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([height, 0]);

    var color = d3.scale.category20();

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left");

    var line = d3.svg.line()
      .interpolate("basis")
      .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.date);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.temperature);
      });

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var data = d3.tsv.parse(myData);

    color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
      return key !== "date";
    }));

    data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    });

    var cities = color.domain().map(function(name) {
      return {
        name: name,
        values: data.map(function(d) {
          return {
            date: d.date,
            temperature: +d[name]
          };
        })
      };
    });

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
      return d.date;
    }));

    y.domain([
      d3.min(cities, function(c) {
        return d3.min(c.values, function(v) {
          return v.temperature;
        });
      }),
      d3.max(cities, function(c) {
        return d3.max(c.values, function(v) {
          return v.temperature;
        });
      })
    ]);

    var legend = svg.selectAll('g')
      .data(cities)
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'legend');

    legend.append('rect')
      .attr('x', width - 20)
      .attr('y', function(d, i) {
        return i * 20;
      })
      .attr('width', 10)
      .attr('height', 10)
      .style('fill', function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      });

    legend.append('text')
      .attr('x', width - 8)
      .attr('y', function(d, i) {
        return (i * 20) + 9;
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
      });

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Temperature (ºF)");

    var city = svg.selectAll(".city")
      .data(cities)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "city");

    city.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        return line(d.values);
      })
      .style("stroke", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      });

    city.append("text")
      .datum(function(d) {
        return {
          name: d.name,
          value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]
        };
      })
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.temperature) + ")";
      })
      .attr("x", 3)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
      });

    var mouseG = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "mouse-over-effects");

    mouseG.append("path") // this is the black vertical line to follow mouse
      .attr("class", "mouse-line")
      .style("stroke", "black")
      .style("stroke-width", "1px")
      .style("opacity", "0");

    var lines = document.getElementsByClassName('line');

    var mousePerLine = mouseG.selectAll('.mouse-per-line')
      .data([cities])
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "mouse-per-line");

    mousePerLine.selectAll('.mouse-per-line')
      .data([cities])
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width", width / 2)
      .attr("height", 90)
      .style("padding", "5px")
      .style("stroke", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      })
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      })
      .style("stroke-width", "1px")
      .style("opacity", "0")
      .attr('x', 10)
   .attr('y',-45);


    mousePerLine.selectAll('.mouse-per-line')
      .data(cities)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .style("stroke", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      })
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      })
      .style("stroke-width", "1px")
      .style("opacity", "0");

    mousePerLine.selectAll('.text')
      .data(cities)
      .enter().append("text")
      .attr("transform", "translate(15,13)");

    mouseG.append('svg:rect') // append a rect to catch mouse movements on canvas
      .attr('width', width) // can't catch mouse events on a g element
      .attr('height', height)
      .attr('fill', 'none')
      .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
      .on('mouseout', function() { // on mouse out hide line, circles and text
        d3.select(".mouse-line")
          .style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line rect")
          .style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
          .style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
          .style("opacity", "0");
      })
      .on('mouseover', function() { // on mouse in show line, circles and text
        d3.select(".mouse-line")
          .style("opacity", "1");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line rect")
          .style("opacity", "0.5");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
          .style("opacity", "1");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
          .style("opacity", "1");
      })
      .on('mousemove', function() { // mouse moving over canvas
        var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
        d3.select(".mouse-line")
          .attr("d", function() {
            var d = "M" + mouse[0] + "," + height;
            d += " " + mouse[0] + "," + 0;
            return d;
          });
  d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line")
          .attr("foo", function(d, i) {
            var xDate = x.invert(mouse[0]);
            var  bisect;
   var  heights = [];
   
   d3.selectAll('circle')
    .attr("transform", function(d,j) {
     bisect = d3.bisector(function(d) {
                return d.date;
              }).right;
            idx = bisect(d.values, xDate);

            var beginning = 0,
              end = lines[i].getTotalLength(),
              target = null;

            while (true) {
              target = Math.floor((beginning + end) / 2);
              pos = lines[j].getPointAtLength(target);
              if ((target === end || target === beginning) && pos.x !== mouse[0]) {
                break;
              }
              if (pos.x > mouse[0]) end = target;
              else if (pos.x < mouse[0]) beginning = target;
              else break; //position found
            }
    heights[j] = pos.y;
    return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + pos.y + ")";
    });
   var avgheight = 0; 
   for(var z = 0; z < heights.length ; z++){
    avgheight = avgheight + heights[z];
   } 
   avgheight = avgheight/d.length;
      d3.select(this).selectAll('rect')
    .attr("transform", function(d,i) {
     return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + avgheight + ")";
    });
   var rectangleText = "";
   for(var t = 1; t < heights.length ; t++) {
    rectangleText = rectangleText + "<br/>" + y.invert(heights[t]).toFixed(2);
   } 
            d3.select(this).selectAll('text').text(function(d,i) { return y.invert(heights[i]).toFixed(2)}).attr("transform", function(d,i) {
     return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + (avgheight  + 30 - (i*25)) + ")";
    }).attr("dx", '20px');   
            return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + pos.y + ")";
          });
      });
```

```css
body {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
    }
    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
    .x.axis path {
      display: none;
    }
    .line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you so much for your response. I went through your explanation, it's really great. You are correct, the look and feel was better in the earlier one as compared to this one because this can be some what confusing. Well thanks for such a great solution and explanation. : )

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
    }
    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
    .x.axis path {
      display: none;
    }
    .line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var myData = "date New York San Francisco Austin\n\
20111001 63.4 62.7 72.2\n\
20111002 58.0 59.9 67.7\n\
20111003 53.3 59.1 69.4\n\
20111004 55.7 58.8 68.0\n\
20111005 64.2 58.7 72.4\n\
20111006 58.8 57.0 77.0\n\
20111007 57.9 56.7 82.3\n\
20111008 61.8 56.8 78.9\n\
20111009 69.3 56.7 68.8\n\
20111010 71.2 60.1 68.7\n\
20111011 68.7 61.1 70.3\n\
20111012 61.8 61.5 75.3\n\
20111013 63.0 64.3 76.6\n\
20111014 66.9 67.1 66.6\n\
20111015 61.7 64.6 68.0\n\
20111016 61.8 61.6 70.6\n\
20111017 62.8 61.1 71.1\n\
20111018 60.8 59.2 70.0\n\
20111019 62.1 58.9 61.6\n\
20111020 65.1 57.2 57.4\n\
20111021 55.6 56.4 64.3\n\
20111022 54.4 60.7 72.4\n";

    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 80,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 50
      },
      width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;

    var x = d3.time.scale()
      .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([height, 0]);

    var color = d3.scale.category20();

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left");

    var line = d3.svg.line()
      .interpolate("basis")
      .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.date);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.temperature);
      });

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var data = d3.tsv.parse(myData);

    color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
      return key !== "date";
    }));

    data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    });

    var cities = color.domain().map(function(name) {
      return {
        name: name,
        values: data.map(function(d) {
          return {
            date: d.date,
            temperature: +d[name]
          };
        })
      };
    });

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
      return d.date;
    }));

    y.domain([
      d3.min(cities, function(c) {
        return d3.min(c.values, function(v) {
          return v.temperature;
        });
      }),
      d3.max(cities, function(c) {
        return d3.max(c.values, function(v) {
          return v.temperature;
        });
      })
    ]);

    var legend = svg.selectAll('g')
      .data(cities)
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'legend');

    legend.append('rect')
      .attr('x', width - 20)
      .attr('y', function(d, i) {
        return i * 20;
      })
      .attr('width', 10)
      .attr('height', 10)
      .style('fill', function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      });

    legend.append('text')
      .attr('x', width - 8)
      .attr('y', function(d, i) {
        return (i * 20) + 9;
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
      });

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Temperature (ºF)");

    var city = svg.selectAll(".city")
      .data(cities)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "city");

    city.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        return line(d.values);
      })
      .style("stroke", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      });

    city.append("text")
      .datum(function(d) {
        return {
          name: d.name,
          value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]
        };
      })
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.temperature) + ")";
      })
      .attr("x", 3)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
      });

     // **************************************************************************************** //

    var mouseG = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "mouse-over-effects");

    mouseG.append("path") // this is the black vertical line to follow mouse
      .attr("class", "mouse-line")
      .style("stroke", "black")
      .style("stroke-width", "1px")
      .style("opacity", "0");

    var lines = document.getElementsByClassName('line');

    var mousePerLine = mouseG.selectAll('.mouse-per-line')
      .data([cities])
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "mouse-per-line");

    mousePerLine.selectAll('.mouse-per-line') // Rectangle
      .data([cities])
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", 110)
      .style("padding", "5px")
      .style("stroke", "#272525")
      .style("fill", "#272525")
      .style("stroke-width", "1px")
      .style("opacity", "0")
      .attr('x', 10)
      .attr('y', -45);

    mousePerLine.selectAll('.mouse-per-line') // Circle
      .data(cities)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .style("stroke", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      })
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      })
      .style("stroke-width", "1px")
      .style("opacity", "0");

    mousePerLine.append("text")
      .attr("class", "DateText");
    mousePerLine.selectAll('.mouse-per-line') // Text
      .data(cities)
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .attr("class", "ValueText")
      .attr("transform", "translate(15,13)")
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      })
      .style("font-weight", "bold")
      .style("font-size", "10pt");

    mouseG.append('svg:rect') // append a rect to catch mouse movements on canvas
      .attr('width', width) // can't catch mouse events on a g element
      .attr('height', height)
      .attr('fill', 'none')
      .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
      .on('mouseout', function() { // on mouse out hide line, circles and text
        d3.select(".mouse-line")
          .style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line rect")
          .style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
          .style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
          .style("opacity", "0");
      })
      .on('mouseover', function() { // on mouse in show line, circles and text
        d3.select(".mouse-line")
          .style("opacity", "1");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line rect")
          .style("opacity", "1");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
          .style("opacity", "1");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
          .style("opacity", "1");
      })
      // **************************************************************************************** //

    .on('mousemove', function() { // mouse moving over canvas
      var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
      d3.select(".mouse-line")
        .attr("d", function() {
          var d = "M" + mouse[0] + "," + height;
          d += " " + mouse[0] + "," + 0;
          return d;
        });

      d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line")
        .attr("foo", function(d, i) {
          var xDate = x.invert(mouse[0]);
          var bisect;
          var heights = [];

          var xDateValue = /\w*.\s.\d.\d*.\d*.:\d*.:\d*/.exec(xDate);
          // console.log(xDateValue);

          d3.selectAll('circle')
            .attr("transform", function(d, j) {
              bisect = d3.bisector(function(d) {
                return d.date;
              }).right;
              idx = bisect(d.values, xDate);

              var beginning = 0,
                end = lines[i].getTotalLength(),
                target = null;

              while (true) {
                target = Math.floor((beginning + end) / 2);
                pos = lines[j].getPointAtLength(target);
                if ((target === end || target === beginning) && pos.x !== mouse[0]) {
                  break;
                }
                if (pos.x > mouse[0]) end = target;
                else if (pos.x < mouse[0]) beginning = target;
                else break; //position found
              }
              heights[j] = pos.y;
              return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + pos.y + ")";
            });
          var avgheight = 0;
          for (var z = 0; z < heights.length; z++) {
            avgheight = avgheight + heights[z];
          }
          avgheight = avgheight / d.length;

          d3.select(this).selectAll('rect')
            .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
              return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + avgheight + ")";
            });
          var rectangleText = "";
          for (var t = 1; t < heights.length; t++) {
            rectangleText = rectangleText + "<br/>" + y.invert(heights[t]).toFixed(2);
          }

          d3.select(this)
            .select(".DateText")
            .text(xDateValue)
            .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
              return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + (avgheight - 25) + ")";
            })
            .attr("dx", '20px')
            .style("fill", "white")
            .style("font-weight", "bold")
            .style("font-size", "10pt");;

          d3.select(this)
            .selectAll('.ValueText')
            .text(function(d, i) {
              return d.name + "  " + y.invert(heights[i]).toFixed(2)
            })
            .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
              return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + (avgheight + 50 - (i * 25)) + ")";
            })
            .attr("dx", '20px');

          return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + pos.y + ")";
        });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

After so many hurdles I found some solution to show the data of both X and Y axis in a multi line graph using D3 library. I hope it helps any one who is trying the same.